# How to instantiate a generic recursive class in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, recursion

My problem is that I am using a class not developed by me (I took it from Microsoft Azure SDK for Java). The class is called Node and you can see it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-resources/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/fluentcore/dag/Node.java).

As you can see the class is a generic class declared recursively like this:

```
public class Node<DataT, NodeT extends Node<DataT, NodeT>> {
      ...
}
```

When I try to instantiate it I don't know how to do it. I am doing this but I know IT IS NOT the way because it has no end:

```
Node<String, Node<String, Node<String, Node<...>>>> myNode = new Node<String, Node<String, Node<String, Node<...>>>>;
```

I hope you understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: May declaring it abstract would clarify

Comment: @ArneBurmeister Exactly my point! It doesn't help at all that the `Node` class is not abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare a class which extends `Node` so you can use the name of the class:

```
class StringNode extends Node<String, StringNode> {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to extend `Node` like:

```
class MyNode<T> extends Node<T, MyNode<T>> {
}
```

and then instantiate it like:

```
Node<String, MyNode<String>> node1 = new MyNode<String>();
```

or

```
MyNode<Integer> node2 = new MyNode<Integer>();
```

Comment: Fine and flexible way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wildcard in your variable declaration:

```
Node<String, ?> n = new Node<>();
```

Or you can create an explicit subclass

```
class StringNode extends Node<String, StringNode> { }
```

and instantiate it via

```
Node<String, ?> n = new StringNode();
```

or

```
StringNode n = new StringNode();
```